# Is the intersection of two dense Baire subsets dense?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $Y$ be a compact metric space and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ two dense subsets of $Y$ which are Baire spaces. Is $Z_1\cap Z_2$ dense in $Y$?

The answer is obviously yes if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are dense $G_{\delta}$ subsets, but not every dense subset which is a Baire space is a dense $G_{\delta}$.

Comment: Aren't the rationals a $G_{\delta}$ set?

Comment: No they aren't, because a dense $G_{\delta}$ is a Baire space.

Comment: A Bernstein set and its complement? They are Baire, see https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/#:~:text=Bernstein%20Sets%20Are%20Baire%20Spaces&text=)%20and%20hence%20is%20also%20a,sets%20are%20called%20Bernstein%20sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ might even be disjoint, for example take as $Z_1$ a Bernstein set in $[0,1]$ and as $Z_2$ its complement, there is a [beautiful blog post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/bernstein-sets-are-baire-spaces/) by Dan Ma detailing why such spaces are Baire.

An interesting question is whether there are examples with $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ well beheaved, say Borel, but I don't see a simple answer in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that Baire spaces could be so exotic.

Comment: @user558840 Most Baire spaces one usually encounters are either completely metrizable or compact Hausdorff and those are very well beheaved. Outside of those nice classes everything gets ugly, for example it isn't even true that the product of two Baire spaces is Baire in general